# Load external XML file in a XmlDataProvider

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf

I will load a Xml file into my project without including it to my Solution. Normally to load it is:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="MyList" Source="Packages.xml" XPath="Packages"/>
```

Where in the source "Packages.xml" must be a XML that is included in my project. **But how can I read a Xml that is not included in the proyect?**

Thank you very much!

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Source` property to an Uri that contains the path name of the XML file:

```
string xmlFilePath = ...
var xmlDataProvider = (XmlDataProvider)Resources["MyList"];

xmlDataProvider.Source = new Uri(xmlFilePath);
```